# Loop through a list of URLs multi-threading and check return code in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I have to loop through a list of over 4000 urls and check their http return code in python.

**Url.txt:** Contains a list of 4000 urls with one url per line.

The script takes a long time to run and I wanted to incorporate multi-threading to improve speed but not sure if I have done it properly.

It sure doesn't seem like it is working fast enough.

```
#! /usr/bin/python

# To just check a site and get the URL code
#import urllib.request
#print(urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.stackoverflow.com").getcode())
#############################################################################

import time
import requests

start = time.time()

from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool
pool = Pool(8) # Number of concurrent threads

#input file
URLS = open("url.txt","r")

#output file
file = open('output.csv', 'w') 

#############################################################################

GREEN = '\033[92m'
YELLOW = '\033[93m'
RED = '\033[91m'
ENDC = '\033[0m'


def main():
    with open('url.txt') as f:

        url = f.read().splitlines()
        print( "\nTesting URLs.", time.ctime())

        all_text = pool.map(checkUrls,url)
        print("closing p")
        pool.close()
        pool.join()
            #checkUrls()
        print("Press CTRL+C to exit")
        #I don't need this sleep any longer. Can I remove the next line?
        time.sleep(100000) #Sleep 10 seconds

def checkUrls(url):
    count = 0
    status = "N/A"
    try:
        status = checkUrl(url)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        status = "DOWN"
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError:
        status = "HttpError"
    except requests.exceptions.ProxyError:
        status = "ProxyError"
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout:
        status = "TimeoutError"
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectTimeout:
        status = "connectTimeout"                        
    except requests.exceptions.ReadTimeout:
        status = "ReadTimeout"                                    
    except requests.exceptions.TooManyRedirects:
        status = "TooManyRedirects"                                
    except requests.exceptions.MissingSchema:
        status = "MissingSchema"                                                
    except requests.exceptions.InvalidURL:
        status = "InvalidURL"                                
    except requests.exceptions.InvalidHeader:
        status = "InvalidHeader"                                                
    except requests.exceptions.URLRequired:
        status = "URLmissing"                                
    except requests.exceptions.InvalidProxyURL:
        status = "InvalidProxy"                                                
    except requests.exceptions.RetryError:
        status = "RetryError"                                                                              
    except requests.exceptions.InvalidSchema:
        status = "InvalidSchema"                                  

    printStatus(url, status, count)

    count+=1
    time_elapsed = datetime.now() - start_time


def checkUrl(url):
    r = requests.get(url, timeout=5)
    #print r.status_code
    return str(r.status_code)


def printStatus(url, status, count):
    color = GREEN

    count= count+1
    if status != "200":
        color=RED

    #print(color+status+ENDC+' '+ url)
    print(str(count)+'\t' + color+status+ENDC+' '+ url)
    file.write(str(count)+'\t' + color+status+ENDC+' '+ url +'\n')

    #print('Time elapsed (hh:mm:ss.ms) {}'.format(time_elapsed))  

end = time.time()
print(end - start) 

# Main app
#
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has something called the [GIL (Global Interface Lock)](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock),  which restricts the number of thread that can concurrently run to one. This limitation only concerns pure Python code (so modules written in C, like `numpy` might release this lock).

Have you tried using `multiprocessing.Pool`, instead of `multiprocessing.dummy.Pool`?

As an additional point, Python has an official style-guide, [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It recommends using `lower_case` for variables and functions.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I decided to change the code to this version, which runs a lot faster:

```
import urllib.request
import urllib.error
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

start = time.time()

file = open('url10.txt', 'r', encoding="ISO-8859-1")
urls = file.readlines()

print(urls)


def checkurl(url):
    try:
        conn = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    except urllib.error.HTTPError as e:
        # Return code error (e.g. 404, 501, ...)
        # ...
        print('HTTPError: {}'.format(e.code) + ', ' + url)
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        # Not an HTTP-specific error (e.g. connection refused)
        # ...
        print('URLError: {}'.format(e.reason) + ', ' + url)
    else:
        # 200
        # ...
        print('good' + ', ' + url)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Pool(processes=20)
    result = p.map(checkurl, urls)

print("done in : ", time.time()-start)
```

---

### Url.txt file contains a list of urls

```
http://yahoo.com
http://www.google.com
```

I have about a 1000 urls to check and it seems to work. Any suggestions to improve the functionality?

Comment: multiprocessing is not scalable for a solution that involves IO beyond the number of processors, an IO bound task such as url loading from 10000 different places is best done using gevent or eventlet